# php simple str_replace template date format

Tags: php, templates, date, format, str-replace

i am trying to make a simple template system for a website news module. here are my codes.

```
$temp = "#title#, <br>#date(d-m-Y)#<br> #story#";
$data = array(title=>"this is a title", date=>1350498600, story=>"some news story.");
```

i have found this simple class on stackoverflow and tried to use it for my purpos.

```
class EmailTemplate
{
     private $_template = '';

    public function __construct($template)
    {
        $this->_template = $template;
    }

    public function __set($key,$value)
    {
        $this->_template = str_replace("#" . $key . "#",$value,$this->_template);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->_template;
    }
}
```

i use it like :

```
    $Template = new EmailTemplate($temp);
    $Template->title = $data['title'];
    $Template->date = $data['date'];
    $Template->story = $data['story'];
    echo $Template;
```

all works fine for title and story but as it comes to date i have problem because i want to format date as defined in template i.e. date(d-m-Y). How can i do that ??

The template is coming from different table and news is coming from different table. and date format is going to be defined in template.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Template->date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data['date']));
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer but in template placeholder is #date(d-m-Y)# so $Template->date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data['date'])); is not working

Comment: change the template to #date#?

Comment: i can do it but I need to format date from template not while assigning .

Comment: Right, no, I'm lost now. Is there any way you can make your question clearer?

Comment: ok let me clear it a bit more. data array is fixed with three items title, date, story. But in my template i might use date in two place like date(d) at one place and date(d-m-Y) at another place.

Comment: In that case, I'd insert your date as the normal(?) unix-epoch-like string of gibberish, and only format it when you output it. That way, it doesn't matter what you want to format it as (you can just pass it through date() any way you fancy).

Answer (score 0):

you would need to accept `date('d-m-Y')` as a property of the class.  this is not allowed, it would seem you need to either change the placeholder to something acceptable as a property of the class or change the class, perhaps add a method specific to that field.

I believe you can not accomplish what you want with the technique you are are using.

Comment: i am not good with classes this class i am using is also from stakeoverflow, but i understand functions if someone can provide me one other than class!

Answer (score 0):

I've got one, little more complex solution using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

First of all you need storage class, let's say:

```
class TemplateStorage {
    // Okay, you should have getter&setter for element, but this is just an example
    public $variables = array(); // Common variables like title
    public $functions = array(); // Function mappings like 'date' => 'wrapper_date'

    public function HandleMatch($match); // Will be shown later
}
```

Then you should have some kind of wrapper, you may integrate it into `TemplateStorage`, extend classes, do whatever you want (this may come in handy if you'll need to integrate this with users timezone settings):

```
function WapperDate($dateFormat){
   // Set timezone, do whatever you want, add %... or use date straight forward
   return date( $dateFormat);
}
```

Then RegEx which allows you to call what you need (matches everything between `#`, ignore spaces):

```
$regEx = '~#\\s*(.+?)\\s*#~';
```

Okay, now we can take care about `HandleMatch` (we know the structure of `$match`):

```
public function HandleMatch($match)
{
    $content = match[1];

    // Let's check whether it contains (. No? May be variable
    $pos = strpos( $content, '(');
    if( $pos === false){
       if( isset( $this->variables[ $content])){
           return $this->variables[ $content];
       }
    }

    // Allow "short calling" #date# = #date()# if no variable is set
    $argument = '';
    $function = $content;

    if( $pos !== false){
        // Last char must be )
        if( substr( $content, -1) != ')'){
            throw new Exception('Invalid format: ' . $content);
        }

        // Split into pieces
        $argument = substr( $content, $pos+1, -1);
        $function = substr( $content, $pos);
    }

    if( !isset($this->functions[$function])){
       throw new Exception( 'Unknown requested TemplateProperty: ' . $function);
    }

    // Call requested item
    return $this->functions[$function]($argument);
}
```

And now pull it all together:

```
$storage = new TemplateStorage();
$storage->variables['title'] = 'Lorem ipsum sit dolor';
$storage->functions['date'] = 'WrapperDate';
preg_replace_callback( $regEx, array( $storage, 'HandleMatch'), $text);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, for your answer can you please provide me full class for my example ? i am not very good with classes !!

Comment: @alladeen it's already there, you only need to move function into the class